# WiX. Run a custom action when a checkbox is checked

Tags: checkbox, wix, custom-action

I have two files Product.wxc there i wrote

```
<Property Id="CheckBoxProp">
```

and Custom Action

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" After="InstallInitialize">
        CheckBoxProp=1 
      </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In another file MyCheckBoxDlg.wxc I wrote UI dialog there I described checkbox

```
<Control Type="CheckBox" Id="MyCheckBoxID" Width="125" Height="26" X="26" Y="124" Text="My text" Property="CheckBoxProp" CheckBoxValue="1" />
```

All publishs I wrote in another file where I have a DialogRef to MyCheckBoxDlg

When I start my installation customaction doesn't see change of value CheckBoxProp.

Help plz! I wait for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CheckBoxProp is a private not a secure (public) property.  Change it to CHECKBOXPROP and use the Secure attribute to get it listed in the [SecureCustomProperties property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).