# wix run a custom action when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: checkbox, properties, wix

I try to run custom action when the checkbox is unchecked (it is checked by default). I have read this topic, the situation is alike as it seems to me.
[WiX. Run a custom action when a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442670/wix-run-a-custom-action-when-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Maybe, it is important that the dialog is opened during uninstall. So, the problem is the property is not changed if the checkbox is unchecked.

```
  <Control Id="LeaveFiles"
         Type="CheckBox"
         Height="18"
         Width="295"
         X="26" Y="58"
         Text="Not to delete custom files"
         Property="CHECKBOXPROP"
         CheckBoxValue="1" />
```

and here is my prop and custom action in Product.wxs

```
<Property Id="CHECKBOXPROP" Secure="yes">1</Property>

<CustomAction Id="DeleteAll" Directory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" ExeCommand="cmd /C RD &quot;./Logs&quot; /s /q"
              Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="DeleteAll" After="RemoveFiles">CHECKBOXPROP=0</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Also I have question about InstallExecuteSequence - can\should i write CHECKBOXPROP=0 AND REMOVE="ALL"? I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code.

The problem in your code was you have tried to check for property value zero, which is not defined.
You have written in your code CheckBoxValue="1" , so the value will be 1 if checked and there will be no value if not checked.

So write the condition as `<![CDATA[CHECKBOXPROP <> 1]]>` When the value is not 1 the custom action will run.

You the following code

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="DeleteAll" After="RemoveFiles"><![CDATA[CHECKBOXPROP <> 1]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: @Lili, If it works accept it as the answer or the question will be kept unanswered